# Can someone explain this model.save() behavior in Django, test server vs. Apache?

Tags: mysql, django, apache, model

I have a Django model that contains, among other things, a *product* field restricted to 128 characters:

```
class SKU(models.Model):
    ...
    product = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=False)
    ...
```

At one point in the app, I read in some user data and make a SKU out of it, and save it.  As it turns out, sometimes the data that goes into the *product* field exceeds the specified size of 128 characters.  When my app is being served by Apache through WSGI, the **sku.save()** command emits this warning:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py:114: Warning: Data truncated for column 'product' at row 1
```

… but that's all it is, a warning.  The sku is saved, and the contents of the *product* field are truncated to 128 chars.  However, when I'm testing this with Django's built-in test server, the **sku.save()** command results in a crash, and the following (abbreviated) stack trace:

```
File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/acdc_cmd/trunk/promotions/promo_parsers.py", line 467, in createKitsAndContents  

theSKU.save()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 463, in save
self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
...
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 114, in execute  
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 204, in execute
if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 117, in _warning_check
warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
Warning: Data truncated for column 'product' at row 1
```

In this case, the **sku.save()** crashes the program.  This means that the result of the import operation is different on the test server and when served by Apache.  I have the following questions:

1. How does Django do different stuff in these two (Apache vs. test server) cases?
2. Is there a way to explicitly indicate in my code: save this sku, it's okay to truncate the fields according to the model definition?
3. Is there a better way to handle this?

Wrt #3, I can imagine introspecting into the model's field definition, and manually truncating the character string before I try to save it; but that's a lot of messing around.  I suspect there's a front-door way to accomplish this, but I can't find it.

Comment: Old versions of `mysql` and new versions with the _don't truncate_ option specified behaves that way. Related to production/development server I don't have an answer :( It seems is raising the same problem in both, apache raise a warning and go on and dev server raises the warning and stop. Don't know why they behave diferently. Does apache give 500 internal error??

Comment: Nope.  All it reports is quoted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed is a weird situation. My recommendations about it are here:

First, you should try to avoid the situation at all. No matter if apache save the data right, you should try to remove all the warnings.

The best way to do this is by truncating yourself the data in all relevant places. Is not difficult nor messed.

First, I suggest you include some `javascript` code to the form to give the user the feedback that he's doing something wrong as soon as possible. With the client-side code secure, you should move on and add the line

```
product=forms.CharField(max_length=128 ...)
```

in the `SKUForm`(no matter it is a normal `Form` or a `ModelForm`. I know you said that instrospecting into the model would be very messy but this might be a severe security issue so is worth doing it. You can manually truncate the string overriding the `save` method in either your model or your form -or in both if you really feel paranoic :).

It would be a lot simpler to do something like this:

```
request.POST['product']=request.POST['product'][:128]
```

but sadly that won't work because request.POST is of type `QueryDict` and is inmutable, so you can't modify it. You could copy the dictionary to a new one and pass that object to the form instead of request.POST but I don't know what would be more messy.

I'm sorry I don't have the answer to why Django behaves different in production/dev environment. I know old versions of MySql behave the way that you describe (truncating if the varchar is longer than specified, and new versions forbid this but you cant turn it on twisting some internals settings in the database engine.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: You're welcome. Will love to know if you ever find out what was all this about :)